# How do I rotate a text and then draw in graphicsmagick?

Tags: node.js, graphicsmagick, gm

How do I rotate a text and then draw in graphicsmagick?
It a simple question, but I couldn't understand it from the API.

Help would be appreciated. Thank you.
I am using gm by the way, but doing it from the command line is enough also.

Also, there is an open issue about this subject.
https://github.com/aheckmann/gm/issues/660

OpenCV or Imagemagick alternative is possible, if we can not do it with graphicsmagick.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Rotate a text and draw **what**? **Where**? Maybe show an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Mark Setchell. The question is ambiguous. In ImageMagick, you can draw rotated text in a number of ways. The -annotate function will do that via its arguments. You can also create a new text image using label: and then rotate that and compose it over your background image. See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/ and http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#annotate

Input:

[image]

```
convert logo.jpg -font Arial -pointsize 64 -fill red -gravity center -annotate 20x20+0+0 "TESTING" logo_test.jpg
```

or alternately using -draw

```
convert logo.jpg -font Arial -pointsize 64 -fill red -gravity center -draw "rotate 20 text 0,0 'TESTING'" logo_test2.jpg
```

[image]

Sorry, I do not know GraphicsMagick, but it should have a similar operator to -annotate and perhaps the same name.

Comment: In GraphicsMagick's node.js port i found this function `.draw(["rotate -14 text 0,0 " + yourText])` you can give a string of arguments to it, like using the command line tool. This answer pointed me to find this function which didn't cought my eye before. Thank you.

Comment: Of course your text should contain escaped or single quotes in it if you will be using a variable. ex.  `var yourText = "\"sample text\""`

Answer (score 0):

As specified here: http://www.graphicsmagick.org/GraphicsMagick.html#details-draw you can specify additional transformation primitives to *-draw* option of graphicsmagick.

"Rotate" primitive is the thing that you need in this case. You need to specify this primitive before "text" options to get this work.

Example:

```
gm convert -font arial -fill white -gravity Center -draw "rotate 45 text 0,0 'Some text'" img1.jpg img2.jpg
```

Very important to place "rotate {degrees}" primitive before text statement to get this work.